# How to ensure RTK Query does not cache certain endpoints which take sensitive data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, rtk-query

I have an endpoint for authenticating the user, which takes the user's username and password. The request returns a token which the app should then use for all subsequent requests, so I store it in the Redux store.

The tokens have a limited lifetime, so the app has to get a new token every so often. Because of this, I want to store the username and password using the device's secure chain storage (I'm using React Native), not on the Redux store, since doing so make it easy to extract the credentials from the app memory.

But since RTK Query by default caches requests based on the args passed to it, the user credentials will be cached in the Redux store.

So my question is two-fold:

1. Is what I'm saying even sensible? Does the logic for how I want this to work makes sense?
2. If yes, then how do I go about disabling the cache for one specific endpoint for RTK Query?

Answer (score 0):

The point of RTK Query is to put things into a Redux store. That is the core mechanism for everything.
You can do all the requests without it, but if you do a request with it, it will be cached, at least for a while.
That generally would not be much of a concern since a Redux store is just a variable like `const foo = "somethingSecret"` though.

That said, you should probably not store username and password, but a "refresh token" that you get from your server.
And usually, **you** should not store that yourself, but your fetch implementation should do that for you - in the form of a cookie.
This also works in React Native.

Your server just sets the cookie for both the token and the refresh token as a `httpOnly` cookie and you cannot even access them from JavaScript. In JS, you just say `credential: "include"` and all your requests to that same domain will contain those tokens.
Manually handling those tokens if you can avoid it is always bad security practice.